# Will the Oauth consent screen need re-verification if it's migrated to another GCP org?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have a GCP project with a verified consent screen for calendar API access. I may want to transfer this project to a different Google workspace account. This means transferring to a different GCP organisation.

In principle, this process is described here:  https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration

But what happens to the consent screen when the project is migrated? Will it need re-verification?

For example, the "Developer Contact Information" email needs to belong to the google workspace account. What happens to it when the project is moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new verification must not be required after a migration as long as no changes or updates are made to the project.

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#oauth_consent_screen):

> To avoid loss of access for members of the source organization:
>
> 1. Update the OAuth consent screen to be external instead of internal.
> 2. Apps that are marked internal and use    [sensitive data](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#sensitive-scopes)
>    do not need to apply for app verification. If the app uses sensitive
>    data,    then when the consent screen is updated to external, the
>    users of the source    organization will see an    [unverified app
>    screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865)    before the
>    authorization screen. To avoid this, apply for    [app
>    verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#ver-prep)
>    for the use of sensitive or restricted scopes.

If you have an external OAuth consent screen already verified, then no need to go through these steps, only be careful and create new users in the destination organization matching your source organization members so that you do not need to change the OAuth consent screen configuration.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, this refers to an INTERNAL google consent screen. My question was aiming at a verified project with external users.

Comment: But this is interesting, since it implies that you *CAN* indeed migrate a consent screen to another organization. It’s not clear though if this will require re-verification afterwards.

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert after performing an internal research I found the specific information that you need, just edited the answer.

Comment: thank you so much for investigating. Really. You are making my day here. What exactly do you mean with "new users in the destination organisation matching your source organisation"? You mean the users that are used for "user support email" and "developer contact information" ? I need to do this somehow before migrating the project, right, so somehow I need these users in both organisations at the same time?

Comment: Exactly, you need to add the same users in the destination organization so you don't have to change the consent screen configuration, if you change any information in the consent screen you will need to go through the verification process again.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.